# 2010 Vovlo XC 60

Tags: starting, volvo, xc60

I have a 2010 volvo that will start after a battery change. The key fob also gets stuck as well. I have read all kinds of blogs to include touching the battery cables together for 30 seconds and I get nothing.
Also, sometimes while trying to start with nothing on I can hear like a fan or something running though the car is not on.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your post might need some edits...   The Volvo **will** start, or will **NOT** start?  After a battery **change** or did you mean battery **charge**?  What do you mean by a fob getting **stuck**?  Also, fans often run when cars are off. Probably safe to ignore that for now.

Comment: Replace the battery in the fob.  It sounds like the rolling security code isn't being received due to a weak transmitter.  Disconnecting the battery acts as a failsafe.